# Why do Walruses come up in the Beatles lyrics?

Tags: the-beatles

Walruses are mentioned in some songs of *the Beatles* and there is **"Paul is the walrus"** thing.

Is there a deeper meaning to this?

Comment: What is "so much"? Do you have any numbers?

Comment: at first i wrote "what does the walruses got to do with the beatles" but then someone edited it. that wasn't what i meant to ask.

Comment: There's a good piece about the whole Walrus/Paul thing [here](http://turnmeondeadman.com/paul-is-dead-clues-in-i-am-the-walrus/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only two references to walruses in The Beatles' songs, and one is a reference to the other.

- *I Am The Walrus*:  [Inspired by](http://mentalfloss.com/article/30523/who-was-walrus-analyzing-strangest-beatles-song) *The Walrus and the Carpenter* from the *Alice in Wonderland* stories.
- *Glass Onion*:  A [deliberately obtuse](http://www.beatlesbible.com/songs/glass-onion/) lyrical pastiche of references to earlier Beatles songs, designed to confuse listeners who over-interpreted the band's work.

Answer (score 5):

Lennon explained the origins of this song in his 1980 Playboy interview: "The first line was written on one acid trip one weekend. The second line was written on the next acid trip the next weekend, and it was filled in after I met Yoko. Part of it was putting down Hare Krishna. All these people were going on about Hare Krishna, Allen Ginsberg in particular. The reference to 'Element'ry penguin' is the elementary, naive attitude of going around chanting, 'Hare Krishna,' or putting all your faith in any one idol. I was writing obscurely, a la Dylan, in those days." Taken from :http://www.songfacts.com/detail.php?id=138